# See if attribute is being applied to a property that is of type String within the class attribute

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

say I have the attribute:

```
public class Column_Attribute : Attribute
{
    public string DbType { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimaryKey { get; set; }
}
```

then I can apply that attribute to a property as:

```
 [Column_Attribute(DbType = "Integer", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
 public int Id { get; set; }
```

Now how can I get information about the property Id from the attribute class. In other words I want to do something like:

```
public class Column_Attribute : Attribute
{
    // constructor
    public Column_Attribute(){
      // if the property has the name Id do something...
      // OR
      // if this is an attribute of a property do something
      // if this is an attribute of a field do something else

      // If this attribute is targeting a property that is a string do something
    }

    public string DbType { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimaryKey { get; set; }
}
```

**I actually need to know if the attribute is being applied to a property that is a string.**

I know how to do that with reflection but I want to do that inside the attribute class. Is that possible. Hope I am explaining myself correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that without reflection because the code in the constructor will not be executed until you call `GetCustomAttributes()`, which is a part of reflection.

see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> Calling GetCustomAttributes on SampleClass causes an Author object to
>   be constructed and initialized as above

If you want your attribute class to contain the processing code, you could create a method receiving the property name. The property name will be available at the time of calling GetCustomAttributes().